# AWS SCP - allow API call from company's IPs only

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have this SCP apply to all organization accounts to block all API calls not from our company's IPs.

But the problem is it also blocks API calls between AWS services.

In my case it blocks API calls from Sage Maker to S3. What else should I add to resolve this problem?

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "RestrictaccessIP",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "NotIpAddress": {
          "aws:SourceIp": [
            "IP1",
            "IP2"
          ]
        },
        "StringLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalArn": [
            "arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-reserved/sso.amazonaws.com/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Haven't tried anything yet

Comment: Probably not a good idea. For example, it would block requests coming from Amazon EC2 instances that want to access Amazon S3 storage.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes I'm aware of that so I created a S3 endpoint to serve that purpose

Comment: Where did you place the above policy?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I placed it in organization service control policy then applied it to specific account

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to facilitate the communication through AWS PrivateLink and VPC interface endpoints. The documentation here might help - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/infrastructure-give-access.html

As an added bonus, you'd be able to reduce some data transfer costs as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, what I've done so far:
- Created S3 gateway endpoint with FullAccess policy
- Change bucket policy to allow access from S3 endpoint and GroundTruth endpoint (which I take from [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/samurai-vpc-labeling-job.html#sms-vpc-permissions-s3) )

Problem still persists, any idea?